# HTML Rich Text Emails From Phone

Tags: email, html

I'm a teleworker and can work from anywhere in the world. I want to be able to send email messages from my phone without having them switch to plain text. My clients think I'm not working hard if I'm not glued to my computer and the plain text lets them know that I'm using a mobile device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Enhanced Email](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.qs.enhancedemail) claims to support outgoing HTML emails.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check that app out. Hope it works with my secure exchange.